# Check if field contains @

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I am using javascript to check if the fields in my form are not empty.
Everything works great, it also checks on an amount of characters in a field.

But now I would like that the email field will be checked if it contains an '@' and at least one '.' otherwise it should give the (same) error message.

I hope someone can help me!

**Fiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/43vLT/1/

```
function isValid(fldId,len) {
var fld = $("#"+fldId);
var val = fld.val();
window.console && console.log(fld,fldId)
if (val == "" || (len && val.length<len)) {
  fld.css("borderColor","red");
  return false;
}      
fld.css("borderColor","black");
return true;
}

$(function() {
$("form").on("submit",function() {
var errormessage = [];

if (!isValid('naam', 10)) {
  errormessage.push("You forgot to fill in your name ");
}
if (!isValid('email')) {
  errormessage.push("You forgot to fill in your email ");
}

if (errormessage.length>0) {
  window.console && console.log("error present");
  $(".error-messages").html(errormessage.join('<br/>')).fadeIn();
  return false;
}
window.console && console.log("success");
return true;
});
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript

Comment: So you just want email validation? Could use regex:
`/^\s*[\w\-\+_]+(\.[\w\-\+_]+)*\@[\w\-\+_]+\.[\w\-\+_]+(\.[\w\-\+_]+)*\s*$/`

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't do this with just checking to see if it has an email address. I'd use an official regex for matching emails. However, if you can't use regex, use this

```
var str="name@example.com";
if(str.indexOf("@")===-1 ||str.indexOf(".")===-1){
    alert("Your email address must include one @ sign and one period");
}
```

The [W3C](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/input.email.html) uses this regex for its `<input type="email"/>`

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/
```

Comment: thank you for your quick answer! I am searching where I have to place the code in my JS, can't find the solution

Comment: If you're using HTML5, use `<input type="email"/>` or `<input pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/">/"`

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again but would you edit it in my fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/43vLT/1/ still can't seem to make it work

Comment: @ErwinvanEkeren I think it's because you're manually overriding the `onsubmit()`

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet for validating emails would be a regular expression. There isn't really a great "one-size-fits-all" regex that will catch all valid types of emails, since the actual specification allows for quite some interesting addresses to exist, even though they aren't very popular and widely used.
You could take a look [this guide to regular expressions for matching emails](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html)

And in your `isValid` you can add something like this

```
if ('fldId' === 'email') {
    return /.+@.+\..+/.test(val);
}
```

The regex `/.+@.+\..+/` just checks for anything that has some characters, and @, some more characters a dot and some more charaters after that. It's basically the most naive check for email addresses. You can change it for some of the better ones from the link.

Also, you could look into some html5 goodness. `input` fields with `type=email` will get somewhat automatically verified by modern web browsers and there's a pretty good chance they do a better validation than one could find dangling around on the web.

Comment: thank you for your answer, do you think you have time to help me to implant it in my fiddle, I can't seem to make it work?